# Solve a linear function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve this homework assignment?

For a linear function $y=f(x)$, $f(-3) = 25$ and $f(3) = 11$.

Determine $f(-20)$.

I know that with the values $f(-3) = 25$ and $f(3) = 11$ I am suppose to derive a formula and the plug in $f(-20)$ but how do I derive a formula from the values given?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: You don't have to derive the formula. Use the fact that the gradient of a linear function is always constant.

$$\frac{f(-20) - f(3)}{-20 - 3} = \frac{f(3) - f(-3)}{3 - (-3)}$$

Of course, if there is a need, you can derive similarly the formula of $f$. This is, by the way, my favourite method of deriving the equation of a linear function defined by two given points.

$$\frac{f(x) - f(3)}{x - 3} = \frac{f(3) - f(-3)}{3 - (-3)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, the function $f(x)=ax+b$ is actually **affine**, rather linear. Affinity in this case implies that 
$$
f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)=\alpha f(x)+(1-\alpha)f(y).
$$
With $\alpha=\frac{23}{6}$, you have $\alpha(-3)+(1-\alpha)3=-20$, so
$$f(-20)=f\left(\frac{23}{6}(-3)+\frac{-17}{6}(3)\right)=\frac{23}{6}f(-3)+\frac{-17}{6}f(3)=\frac{194}{3}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The slope is $m=\frac{25-11}{-3-3}=\frac{14}{-6}=-2\frac13$.

Now, the $y$-intercept is: $b=y-mx=25-(-2\frac13)(-3)=25-7=18$.

Hence, the formula for the line is: $f(x)=-2\frac13x+18$.

Plug in $x=-20$ to get $f(-20)=-2\frac13(-20)+18=46\frac23+18=\boxed{64\frac23}$.

Comment: -1 because, UH!, mixed fractions.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy I don't see why it's legitimate to downvote because you don't like mixed fractions..

Comment: Evaluate $a\,\frac{b}{c}$ for $a=3$, $b=2$ and $c=11$... Show me mixed fractions being used in any good mathematics or scientific resource. I don't like mixed fractions and I think it is a perfectly good reason to downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Going from $-3$ to $3$ ($6$ units more), the function value changes by $11-25=-14$ units. So the function changes by $-14/6=-7/3$ for an increment of $1$ unit.

Going from $-3$ to $-20$, i.e. a move of $-17$ units, the function value changes by $(-17)\cdot(-7/3)$ and reaches $25+119/3=194/3$.

CHECK:

Going from $3$ to $-20$, i.e. a move of $-23$ units, the function value changes by $(-23)\cdot(-7/3)$ and reaches $11+161/3=194/3$.

GENERALIZATION:

Going from $3$ to $x$, i.e. a move of $x-3$ units, the function value changes by $(x-3)\cdot(-7/3)$ and reaches $11-7/3(x-3)$.

Answer (score -1):

For a linear function, if you know its value at two points, you can fully determine the function. Do you know that general formula for a straight line in the plane? Write that down, and plug in (-3,25) and (3,11) to solve for the coefficients.

Comment: Not an explicit enough answer? Tell me so I can improve my answers in the future. Seeing as it was explicitly called a homework question I thought a hint might be preferred to allow more room to learn.

Answer (score -1):

the fact that $f$ is linear means, in this context, that
$$
f(x) = (1-x)f(0) + xf(1) \tag{1}
$$
(since this is obviously satisfied for $x=0,1$ and a line is determined by any two distinct points)

replacing $x$ with $-x$ gives
$$
f(-x) = (1+x)f(0) - xf(1)
$$

so by addition
$$
f(x)+f(-x) = 2f(0)
$$
for $x= 3$ this gives 
$$
11+25=2f(0)
$$
i.e. $f(0) = 18$

by substitution of either $\pm3$ in (1) we find that $f(1)=\frac{47}3$. knowing the values of $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ allows you to find the value for any $x$ by substitution in (1)